# Read base64 data from InputStream to file C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

my application gets image from clipboard and saves it to server.
getting image is done through java and javascript.
my aspx codebehind receives this data (base64) and writes to file.
here is my  code

```
  byte[] buffer = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];
    int offset = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    while ((cnt = Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, offset, 10)) > 0)
    {
        offset += cnt;
    }
    fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff") + ".png";
    string base64 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"D:\www\images\" + fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
    System.IO.BinaryWriter writer =new BinaryWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    writer.Close();
```

my problem is base64 . i get this string as utf8 encoded. seems this tampers the image and i am not able to open or view them.

[EDIT]
Here is the java code that creates the data

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
sb.append("data:image/").append("png").append(";base64,").append(Base64.encode(stream.toByteArray()));
```

so i will get a string like this
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA..
and using ajax i posts this string to my aspx page

Comment: It is impossible to tell you how to decode the data if we do not know how it was encoded in the first place.  Can you provide the java/javascript code that turns your images into base64 in the first place?

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645088/how-to-decode-a-string-of-text-from-a-base64-to-a-byte-array-and-the-get-the-st/30916342#30916342

this will help you, you wont get a corrupt file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix when you read the input stream before `base64` decoding. For example you could split at the `,`:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];
Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
string[] tokens = data.Split(',');
if (tokens.Length > 1)
{
    byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(tokens[1]);
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff") + ".png";
    string path = Path.Combine(@"D:\www\images", fileName);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, image);
}
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but I can not figure it put... any help would be apreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472731/base64-inputstream-to-string/11472877#comment15148464_11472877