# Conversion from byte array to base64 and back

Tags: c#, encoding, base64, arrays, type-conversion

I am trying to:

1. Generate a byte array.
2. Convert that byte array to base64
3. Convert that base64 string back to a byte array.

I've tried out a few solutions, for example those in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645088/how-to-decode-a-string-of-text-from-a-base64-to-a-byte-array-and-the-get-the-st).

For some reason the initial and final byte arrays do not match. Here is the code used:

```
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
         byte[] originalArray = new byte[32];
         rng.GetBytes(key);
         string temp_inBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(originalArray);
         byte[] temp_backToBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp_inBase64);
    }
```

My questions are:

1. Why do "originalArray" and "temp_backToBytes" not match? (originalArray has length of 32, temp_backToBytes has a length of 44, but their values are also different)
2. Is it possible to convert back and forth, and if so, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The reason the encoded array is longer by about a quarter is that base-64 encoding uses only six bits out of every byte; that is its reason of existence - to encode arbitrary data, possibly with zeros and other non-printable characters, in a way suitable for exchange through ASCII-only channels, such as e-mail.

The way you get your original array back is by using `Convert.FromBase64String`:

```
 byte[] temp_backToBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(temp_inBase64);
```

Comment: That worked, although if base64 uses only 6 out of every 8 bits, I would think the encoding would be shorter?

Comment: @crawfish The encoding uses six out of eight bits in the output, leaving the two most significant ones set to zero. As the result, every group of three bytes (`3*8=24` bits) becomes a group of four bytes (`4*6=24` bits). If the number of bytes in the original is not divisible by three, special markers are added to the end. In your case, the next number divisible by 3 greater than 32 is 33, or `11*3`. This means that the result is `11*4`, or 44 bytes long.

Comment: The group three bytes (3*8=24 bits) becomes 32 bits. ie 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  => b b 1 2 3 4 5 6 | b b 7 8 1 2 3 4 | b b 5 6 7 8 1 2 | b b 3 4 5 6 7 8  assuming MSB (left most bit, or big-endian) padding (b's would be on right end for LSB little-endian).