# Invalid (BLOB Image) URL

Tags: c#, sql-server, angularjs, wcf

**Problem:**
Image cannot be loaded. Chrome-Error message: net:: ERR_INVALID_URL

**MSSQL:**
I created a table with two columns (ID and Image as varbinary(MAX)) and filled it with data using an insert query. The image-links are tested.
[image]

The Query looks like that:

```
INSERT INTO ST_CCG.main.Images(Image)
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM Openrowset (Bulk 'I:\1001.png', Single_Blob) as Image
...
```

**C#:**
Here is how I'm retrieving the data using an byte array to save the binary.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        result.Add(new BusinessObjects.Image
        {
            ID = (ushort)reader.GetInt16(0),
            Image_Binary = (byte[])reader["Image"]
        });
    }
}
```

Created a WCF-Service with WebGet and WebMessageFormat.Json as ResponseFormat.

**AngularJS:**
Loading the data with restangular successfully (Status: 200).
Then I'm trying to show one of the pictures in my view like that:

```
<img ng-src="{{'data:image/PNG; base64,' +customizing.images[0].Image_Binary}}">
```

Then I get the error above. **What am I doing wrong?**

[image]

Comment: You need to print that byte array as a base64 string.

Comment: so, I have to convert it like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634237/conversion-from-byte-array-to-base64-and-back?