# I get error including a byte array field inside a JSON object

Tags: c#, json.net, arrays

I have this class object:

```
public class Gallery
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsUploaded { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image;
    public string JobRef { get; set; }
}
```

I create an instance of it and serialize it using Newton JSON:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject('the object');
```

I then convert the while of this to a byte array and send it my socket listening on another PC:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

using (NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream())
{
    serverStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
   //more code here but not relevant as the error happens on listening PC
}
```

On my listening PC I receive the json as so:

```
using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
    IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
    uint dataRead = BufferSize;
    while (dataRead == BufferSize)
    {
        await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
        request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
        dataRead = buffer.Length;
    }
}

var job = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Gallery>(request.ToString());
```

On this last line I get the error:

```
Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: r. Path '', line 34, position 2.
```

Yet, if I remove the byte array image there is no error. So, is there a certain way to include image arrays with a json object?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Json does not support byte array. You need to convert it to Base64. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634237/conversion-from-byte-array-to-base64-and-back) thread, and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178495/an-efficient-way-to-base64-encode-a-byte-array).