# How to send Hash Value as a Header Using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I am trying to integrate a payment platform to my web application but one of the requirements to query a transaction is to send a hashed value (of certain variables) as a header using a get request. This is what I have tried:

```
string hashcode = "3409877" + "117" + "D3D1D05AFE42AD508";
var hashedBytes = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashcode));
// Get the hashed string.  
var hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
hash = hash.ToString().ToUpper();
var amount_kobo = Convert.ToInt32(model.TransactionAmount * 100);
string url = "https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/collections/api/v1/gettransaction.json?productid=117&transactionreference=" + model.TransactionReference + "&amount=" + amount_kobo;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{

#if DNX451
    // ignore server certificate error
    //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => { return true; };
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
#elif DNXCORE50
    // no implementation for the target DNX
#endif
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();


client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Hash",hash);


    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    string responsestr = "";
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        responsestr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Json(new { success = true, response = responsestr, hash = hash });
    }
}
```

but my hash is not sent, when I inspect the browser after sending the request I do not see my hash header, also am supposed to send the header as a hash type but I have no idea what to do.

I have tried changing this line to:

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("hash"));
```

still it doesn't work.

**Update**
Here is a screenshot of the request headers in the browser
[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsV7V.png)

Seems my header is not sent at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Hash", hash)` instead.

Your code tries to add an Accept request-header, which is used to specify what media types are acceptable for the response.

Comment: Thats not working, i updated my answer with the request headers shown in the browser and my hash header is not there...what could be stopping my header from being sent pls?

Comment: Thanks a lot, removed the  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("hash")); line and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After converting hash to string, your string may contain characters which are restricted for sending in `GET` requests. So you should consider to encode the string by using `Uri.EscapeDataString()` function before sending:

```
hash = Uri.EscapeDataString(hash);
```

Or [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634237/conversion-from-byte-array-to-base64-and-back) `hashedBytes` to Base64
and [encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c) just few symbols after it